# Multilingual tagging in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, tags, tagging

I want to add tags to a model and I also want those tags to be translatable to n languages.

I'm already using i18n gem to translate the contents. What's a proper way to implement translatable tags? Of course those tags will be created by different users.

The only way I thought about was to create a Tag model with `{:id, :translation_id, :language, :name}` using translation_id to link the tag to the original one.

Comment: Could you please mark your question as answered or add some more comments, that we can help you further? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [Globalize 3 gem](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3) could do the job for you.